# How to configure external properties folder and libraries in Liberty server 22.0.0.13

Tags: websphere, classpath, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am working with IBM WebSphere Liberty and I have multiple applications that require the same set of properties and libraries. I would like to configure these common properties and libraries at the server level so that they are available to all applications, without having to define/referencing them at the application level.
I tried below configuraton at server level ,but doesn't seems to be working.

```
<library id="mySharedLib">
    <folder dir="/path/to/folder" />
    <fileset dir="/path/to/fileset/directory" includes="*.jar" />
</library>

<classLoader commonLibraryRef="mySharedLib" />
```

However it works fine , if I define commonLibraryRef at application level as below -

```
<enterPriseApplication id ="app-ear" location="app.ear" name="app-ear">
<classLoader commonLibraryRef="mySharedLib" />
</enterPriseApplication>
```

The problem with this aproach is, when application is deployed through eclipse then application level configuration get overriden . Can anyone suggest a best practice for configuring common properties and libraries in a Liberty server for multiple applications?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you're using Liberty Developer Tools for Eclipse (formerly WebSphere Developer Tools) to deploy the application to the Liberty server?   And you're saying that the tooling-generated application config overwrites the custom config you added to server.xml to hook in the shared library?

Comment: Correcting myself that "WebSphere Developer Tools" (WDT) is related tooling with overlapping function, rather than a former name for "Liberty Developer Tools".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming Scott's comment is right) I think this page in the documentation explains how to set projects to use shared libraries in the tooling

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=library-setting-web-project-use-shared-libraries

It also contains links to a page explaining how to define shared libraries using the tooling.

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: Yes, Scott was correct and configuring shared library as suggested on  above doumentation link worked perfectly fine.  Many Thanks to  Matt and  Scott.